# React Native TextInput: Is it possible to make TextInput move up out of the way of keyboard on iOS same as for Android?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-textinput

I have a `TextInput` field in my React Native app that's near the bottom of the screen. When I click to type in it, on Android the `TextInput` moves up out of the way so that you can still see it while you're typing, but on iOS the `TextInput` doesn't move, so in this case it's obscured behind the keypad.

Is there a way to make the same behaviour on iOS where it moves up out of the way?

Answer (score 0):

Please wrap your textinput container inside [KeyboardAvoidingView](https://reactnative.dev/docs/keyboardavoidingview), or if you are looking for a better solution you can try [KeyboardAwareScrollView](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view), it will surely solve your problem